# What is the terminating part of a xml single/stand-alone tag called?

Tags: xml, terminology

For example, in the case of XML data such as the following:

```
<foo>bar</foo>
```

The opening and closing < and > symbols could be called brackets.

However, in the following:

```
<br />
<data foo="bar" />
<blah a="1" b="2" />
```

Is there a good name for the closing /> token?

> *“There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things!” -- Phil Karlton*

Comment: There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Section 3.1 of the XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags) refers to such tags as "Empty-Element Tags".

```
[44]    EmptyElemTag       ::=      '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '/>'
```

So I would call the `/>` part the "empty element terminator".